# Nested For loops with JSON-VBA

Tags: json, vba

So basically what I am doing here is a double search for some info about a customer. I can do it in a single search, however it will take 5 times the duration of what is supposed to happen here.

First I search by the customer phone number and see the `IDs` of each of his accounts that are linked to his phone number. Then I initiate another `For` loop to search each account through another `xmlhttprequest` to see if he has an active account. The `totalCount` is used to see how many accounts the user has (how many nested arrays are in the first `for` loop request). Then the process should keep looping through the accounts of each user and once it finds the first active account then the whole process should return "`1`" in the corresponding excel adjacent cell.

But I am receiving:

> error 9, subscript out of range

.

**What should I correct in the For loops architecture?**

```
For x = 1 To NumRows
    Dim var As String: var = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2)
    Dim RowNote As String: RowNote = ActiveCell.Row
    Dim http As Object, html As New HTMLDocument, document As Object

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    http.Open "GET", "http://controlpanel.zoho/rest/Accounts/criteria/idlist?AccountPhone=" & var, False
    http.send

    Dim totalCount As Integer, count As Integer
    totalCount = ParseJson(http.responseText)("totalCount")

    For count = 1 To totalCount 'totalCount can be 1 sometimes
        Dim userID As String
        userID = ParseJson(http.responseText)("results")(count)("AccountId")

        Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        http.Open "GET", "http://controlpanel.zoho/rest/AccountDetails/" & userID, False
        http.send

        Dim status As String, jsonDate As Integer
        status = ParseJson(http.responseText)("results")(1)("CustomerStatus")
        If status = "LIVE_ACTIVE" Then 'can introduce Date condition to see if peolpe activated after a certain date
            Sheet3.Cells(RowNote, 3).Value = 1
            Else
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next count
Next x

End Sub
```

**EDIT**: This is a sample of the first JSON array for the first For loop:

URL e.g. `http://controlpanel.zoho/rest/Accounts/criteria/idlist?AccountPhone=67545678`

and the JSON:

```
 {"totalCount":4,
  "messages":[],
   "results":[
        {"Type":"FX","AccountId":14237},
        {"Type":"FX","AccountId":17152},
        {"Type":"FX","AccountId":17553},
        {"Type":"FX","AccountId":17553}
    ],
   "resultClass":"com.zoho.dao.dto.zohoAccountMarketTypeDTO"}
```

and this is a sample of the individual second JSON in the second For loop:

URL 2 e.g. http://controlpanel.zoho/rest/AccountDetails/17152

```
{"totalCount":1,
 "messages":[],
  "results":[
      {"AccountAgrt":false, 
       "accountType":"FOLLOWER",
       "CustomerId":9069,
       "logins":81,
       "CustomerStatus":"LIVE_ACTIVE",
       "dateLastLogin":1510153414000,
       "state":null}
    ],
   "resultClass":"com.zoho.dao.dto.zohoAccountInfoDTO"}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: @CallumDA it seems in the IF statement

Comment: What is the value of rowNote? (also, why is it declared as a `String`? it would make more sense for it to be a `Long`)

Comment: @CallumDA i have many other modules through my project working normally with rownote. This is the first time i have nested loops and i usually use rownote just to iterate through the rows of the spreadsheet. why are you implying the problem would be from rownote?

Comment: only because there's practically nothing else in your IF statement - which is where you're getting the error. The line above could well throw an index out of range error: `ParseJson(http.responseText)("results")(1)("CustomerStatus")
` if there are no results

Comment: @CallumDA what if some users dont have active account yet? maybe this is not explained well within the loops.

Comment: I don't know but is there any way you can check for this instance if ("results")(1)("CustomerStatus") exists? All I can say is that the error message suggests that you're trying to access an index in an array that doesn't exist - this could be a "results" array as per above

Comment: @CallumDA the code is working fine if it finds this condition and it is showing “1”. I’ll check maybe in other accounts if the key exists and will update you

Comment: @CallumDA yes i checked and there is the same key in all kinds of accounts. so the problem isnt here.

Comment: Is the code failing at the end, or somewhere in the middle? In my experience something like count = count + 1 could be causing the very last loop to fail because that last value is one more than items in the array. Try a `debug.Print count, totalCount` just before the `Next`.

Comment: @CindyMeister weird, it is like that: count -> totalCount, 6 -> 5, 2 -> 5, 4 -> 5, again repeating, 6 -> 5, 2 -> 5, 4 -> 5, this pattern is repeated 17 times

Comment: @CindyMeister so yes the counter is bigger than the max counts and is causing the error

Comment: Then you need to do something like `If count >= totalCount Then Exit For`

Comment: @CindyMeister i added sample json that are used above if that does help. with the condition you proposed now the error disappeared but the primary loop isnt looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're re-using your `http` variable inside the loop, so you unload the original response on the first pass through. Just parse the original response and keep that in a variable, then loop over the items, and fetch details for each one.

Untested but something like this should work:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim theListing As Object, theDetails As Object
    Dim totalCount As Integer, count As Integer
    Dim userID As String
    Dim status As String, jsonDate As Integer

    For x = 1 To NumRows

        Set theListing = JSONObject("http://controlpanel.zoho/rest/Accounts/" & _
                                    "criteria/idlist?AccountPhone=" & var)

        totalCount = theListing("totalCount")

        For count = 1 To totalCount 'totalCount can be 1 sometimes

            userID = theListing("results")(count)("AccountId")


            Set theDetails = JSONObject("http://controlpanel.zoho/rest/" & _
                                        "AccountDetails/" & userID)

            status = theDetails("results")(1)("CustomerStatus")
            If status = "LIVE_ACTIVE" Then 'can introduce Date condition to see if peolpe activated after a certain date
                Sheet3.Cells(RowNote, 3).Value = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next count
    Next x

End Sub

'fetch a response as parsed JSON object
Function JSONObject(url As String)
    Dim http As Object
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", url, False
    http.send
    Set JSONObject = parsejson(http.responseText)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Tim for your answer, regarding count = count + 1 it is still inside the for loop although you notified me I shouldn’t modify it. Or am I misunderstanding something.

Comment: I did not try to figure out why that was there; just pointing out it's typically not something you'd do with a For loop variable.  If it works then fine, but it's  not a good practise...

Comment: Tim would I have an iteration problem if sometimes totalcount happens to be 1? Also, once the condition is true, shouldn’t I add: exit for , in order to go and look for other users in the first for loop?

Comment: Yes sounds like `Exit For` is what you need there